# Timestamp in Google sheets

Tags: timestamp

trying to make a timestamp script

Hi, I'm trying to make a timestamp script which puts the date in column A everytime a cell, in the same row, is changed. This for COLUMNS D to Y.
The range of rows is 4 to 28
I found this but the range in columns and rows is not clear for me... so please help

```
function onEdit(e){
 const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 sh.getRange ('A' + e.range.rowStart)
 .setValue (new Date())
 .setNumberFormat ('dd/MM HH:MM');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a cell in "D4:Y28" is edited, you want to put a date in column "A" of the same row with the edited cell.

In your script, all cells are used. So, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (
    sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName ||
    range.columnStart < 4 ||
    range.columnStart > 25 ||
    range.rowStart < 4 ||
    range.rowStart > 28
  ) return;
  sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd/MM HH:MM');
}
```

- In this modification, only when a cell in "D4:Y28" is edited, a date is put into column "A" of the same row with the edited cell.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, so many thanks. Is it also possible that if a row is empty or made empty the date is cleared?

Comment: @Marc Ceulemans Thank you for replying. From `This is exactly what I was looking for, so many thanks.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your new question of ` Is it also possible that if a row is empty or made empty the date is cleared?`, I think that it's yes. If you want a sample script, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Marc Ceulemans Thank you for your response.